# Tradingview Pinescript PSAR Strategy with stoploss (exit) dynamically updating every candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have written a PSAR strategy for pinesript V5 but the final thing that I want it to do is have a input.bool that the user can turn on or off that activates a stoploss.

Currently it sets the stoploss to the point at which the PSAR flips from long to short or visa versa and doesn't wait for the candle to close.

However I feel that it would be better for it to take the current value of the PASR value.
The stoploss is set in the strategy.exit as an if statement depending on the state of the boolean.

The exit would trigger as soon as price crosses the PSAR current value, and does not wait for the candle to close.

I thought that the request.security would pull the current value of the psar but it doesn't seem to do it, at least the way I tried to use it.

I was using it this way which worked

```
// Set up stop loss
stopLoss = ta.valuewhen(ta.crossover(close, psar), psar, 0)
```

This is what I tried to get it working as stated above

```
// Get current value of PSAR
currentPSAR = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, psar)
```

and in the strategy code:

```
    if psarStop
        strategy.exit("Long Stoploss", "Long", stop=currentPSAR, comment=longexitComment)
```

at the very least it works when it crosses the initial PSAR start point upon stop and reversal, but ideally it would perform better.

Thanks in advance if anyone knows, I have checked a number of open shared scripts in the public database and  didn't see any implementation.

Comment: Please try to always include your current code in the questions.